# Dlib add_overlay(): how to set thickness?

Tags: python, image, dlib

Supposing I have the following code:

```
# ...initialization stuff above
win.set_image(frame)
win.add_overlay(my_rect)
```

The problem is that my_rect is drawn **only 1 px thick**!

How can I increase the thickness of the rect?
I cannot find anything in the documentation (very lacking I must say).

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution you can share?

Comment: @lovechillcool As sziraqui said, unfortunately this method does not accept any thickness. You may switch or covert you shapes to something like OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at all [overloads of add_overlay()](http://dlib.net/python/index.html?highlight=image_window#dlib.image_window.add_overlay) method, it is clear that it does not take thickness as a parameter. From documentation -

> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, rectangles: dlib.rectangles,
>   color: dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(255,0,0)) -> None Add a list of
>   rectangles to the image_window. They will be displayed as red boxes by
>   default, but the color can be passed.
>
> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, rectangle: dlib.rectangle, color:
>   dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(255,0,0)) -> None Add a rectangle to the
>   image_window. It will be displayed as a red box by default, but the
>   color can be passed.
>
> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, rectangle: dlib.drectangle,
>   color: dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(255,0,0)) -> None Add a rectangle to
>   the image_window. It will be displayed as a red box by default, but
>   the color can be passed.
>
> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, detection:
>   dlib.full_object_detection, color: dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(0,0,255))
>   -> None Add full_object_detection parts to the image window. They will be displayed as blue lines by default, but the color can be passed.
>
> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, line: dlib.line, color:
>   dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(255,0,0)) -> None Add line to the image
>   window.
>
> add_overlay(self: dlib.image_window, objects: list, color:
>   dlib.rgb_pixel=rgb_pixel(255,0,0)) -> None